# Html.Textbox working where Html.TextboxFor isn't?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm very new to MVC 5 and web programming in general so please bear with me.

I have a view (used to manage user roles) where I have three separate forms, which I more or less copied and pasted from a tutorial. In the tutorial the fields for the forms were created in the following way:

```
Username : @Html.TextBox("Username")
```

Since I wanted the styling to work for them, I changed the code to look more like the default forms in the MVC 5 template, so it ended up looking like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
```

My model `ManageUserRolesViewModel` looks like this (note that at the top of my view I have `@model ManageUserRolesViewModel`):

```
public class ManageUserRolesViewModel
{
    #region Assign Role
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string AssignRoleUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "RoleName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string AssignRoleRole { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Get Roles
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string GetRolesUsername { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Unassign Role
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string UnassignRoleUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "RoleName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string UnassignRoleRole { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Notice how I'm using annotations to load the name of the elements in the ViewModel directly from resources. I'm doing this for localization purposes, and the resources are returning strings in Spanish. **I think this may be the root of my issue, but I'm not sure**.

Then, in my controller I have the following method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult GetRoles(string UserName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
            {
                ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

                ViewBag.RolesForThisUser = this.UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
                ViewBag.Roles = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
            }

            return View("ManageUserRoles");
        }
```

Now, here's what happens: if I use `Username : @Html.TextBox("Username")`, when the method `GetRoles()` gets called in the controler, the `UserName` parameter is there and the user is successfully loaded. If instead I use the

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
```

when the method gets called, the `UserName` parameter is `null`.

My wild guess is that somewhere in the code MVC is looking for `UserName` or `Username` and finding `Usuario` instead, but I am not sure if this is true and in any case, I'd like to know how to solve the issue.

Comment: Why not pass the model to to the Action instead? that way you can take advantage of model binding. And yes, if a different named parameter gets passed in, the value will not be set.

Comment: @Ric How do I do this?

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername, ..)` generates a input for property `GetRolesUsername`, not `UserName`. If you want `UserName` then its `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, ..)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke The reason why I added several Username properties is that when I was using only one for my three-forms view, when I clicked on the `Username` label in form 3, it would focus automatically the textbox in form 1. I thought this would solve the issue.

Comment: You have NOT _added several Username properties_ (if you had your code would not even compile). All you have done is given them the same `DisplayName` (which is used by the `LabelFor()` method). If you want to post back `UserName` then use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => mUsername)` If you want to post back `GetRolesUsername` then use  `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername)`

Comment: @EricTrigo see my answer about the model binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your form has the model defined as:

`@model ManageUserRolesViewModel`

and somewhere in the view:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername, new { @class = "form-control" })`

The action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetRoles(ManageUserRolesViewModel vm)
{
    string userName = vm.GetRolesUsername;
    //rest of code omitted.
}
```

So you do not rely on the `UserName` parameter and can use the view model itself.

if this does not suffice, you could do this:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.GetRolesUsername, new { Name = "UserName" })`

Comment: Thanks, solved my issues. Now I got a couple of questions: 1) Is this the considered best practice approach, passing the whole VM to the action? 2) Since my View consists of three forms one after the other and my VM has the properties for all of them, when I click on the button 'Get Roles' I get validation messages for the required fields in the other forms (because they are null when I'm passing them in the VM for GetRoles). What's the approach to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Eric,

    @Html.TextBox("Username")
    // It creates a html input element with name "Username"
    <input type="text" id=""Username" name="Username" value="" />

And 

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetRolesUsername)
    // It also create a html element with name as it's property name. ie, "GetRolesUsername"
    <input type="text" id=""Username" name="Username" value="@Model.GetRolesUsername" />

    So, if you submit your form, your browser will send parameters as,


    Username = "value in the @html.TeaxtBox()",
    GetRolesUsername = "value in the @html.TextBoxFor()"


So, both values will be passed to your MVC controller. Then you can decide what parameters you want to receive.

    public ActionResult Submit(string Username, string GetRolesUsername)
    {
        // You can get Username and GetRolesUsername here
    }

    public ActionResult Submit(string Username)
    {
        // You tell your controller that I am expecting only one parameter and that is Username
    }

Then there will be a main difference between `@html.TextBox()` and `@html.TextBoxFor()' is, 

`@html.TextBox()` will just create a text element. But, `@html.TextBoxFor()' will create and set value to the element.

Hope this will help you.

If you have any doubts, please feel free to ask me.

**And Grand Welcome To MVC.**

I am also just a beginner in MVC :)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. :)

Comment: Never attempt to override the `value` attribute unless your trying to screw up the model binding procesd